# Creating client side solutions

Tags: visual-studio, client-object-model

i hear people say they want to create client side solutions in visual studio, would that be applicable in the case of visual web part? if i create a visual web part and only write javascript code in it, does that mean am creating client side solution that will be easier later to migrate to the cloud? but at the same time doesn't visual web part contain C# in it by default? i am confused about the idea of writing client side code in sharepoint, what do we use (apart from apps) to create client side stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is right. If the code is written in client side technologies like JSOM or REST in a a visual webpart, it will later be easier to port to app model. This type of code can be put directly inside the SharePoint pages also using web parts like CEWP or Script Editor.

Comment: +1. But I'd like to note that in regard of portability there can be quite some differences between the REST API between on-premise/365 and even App/non-app!

Comment: @eirikb, I agree. There are gaps between what is offered in SharePoint Online and what is present in on-perm. The priority for MS is O365. For example the recent batch support for REST is available in O365 only as of now.

Comment: thank you Nadeem, so what about the code that already exist in visual web part, for example the page_load method, it's c# code, although I didn't write anything in it, but doesn't that make the visual web part component not being deployed to the cloud? how do you deploy the web part you created in visual web part to the cloud?

Comment: @Max, if the visual webpart is part of Farm based solution then it cannot be deployed to cloud. However, Sand boxed solutions can be deployed.